# OUt of gas duringcreation of contract

Tags: contract-development, out-of-gas

I tried to create a smart contract (Token ERC20) with this web IDE : https://remix.ethereum.org
Everything was good.
I taked te same contract and i tried to deploy it with node application by using web3 and solc (for the compiler). When i send the transaction to create the contract, i recieve an error who tell :  "Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas] "

[image]

Can you help me please to fix this problem ?

Comment: There seems to be similar questions here <https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2088618.0> But if you are out of gas and need to know gas costs you can calculate here <https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6mRqkBz3iWcOlRem_mO09GtSKEKrAsfO7Frgx18pNU/edit#gid=0>

Comment: You can increment the gas limit

Comment: Just to be clear.The same contrat was deployed in with the IDE remix.ethereum with the same adress (who have a lot of Eth), Whe n i see the transaction who deployed the smarct contract succefully, i see that she use like "x" Gas limit, so i use the same gasLimit to deploy the same contract and it dosent work. I tried to increase the gasLimit by multiplying the gasLimit by 4 (like 4x GasLimit) and i still have the same error : Out of Gas. I know it's a problem of gas, but i dont know how to solve it, and i'm not sure that the solution it's by incrasing the gas limit :(

Answer (score 1):

Having in mind that you're trying to deploy something which as I understood you have a proof it's working already, leaves a gap for a couple of issues done on your side.

> First one might be that the constructor arguments are not properly
>   set, or that you're sending some wrong-type argument in the
>   constructor.

***Try to log all the arguments before sending the transaction and make sure they're all same types as expected on the contract side.***

> Also, consider checking a bytecode size. If you're having truffle
>   project under `/build/contracts` directory you should find
>   `<contract-name>.json` of the contract you're trying to deploy and
>   make sure that the "deployed_bytecode" is less-equal than 24KB (make
>   sure length of the deployed bytecode is less than 49152 chars)

Hope this helps!